# How to avoid "flicking" of transform/translate when react rerender?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building the game 2048 using react.
The problem i'm having is - that i'm using transform translate, to make the moving animation which is working fine. The problem is that after the move done, i'm re rendering a whole new board with the tiles in the new positions, and although it's a new board without any style on it, there is a split second when the transform is kind of "canceling" ans start going back to it's original position which make the animation kind of flick.
The source code is here: https://github.com/mudale222/2048
The live version is here: https://agile-brushlands-91124.herokuapp.com/
Any help appreciated.
thx

EDIT: as suggested i will try to put the main code concerning the problem.

This is the movement logic:

```
let boardAfterChange = renderBoardChanged(keyPressed(e, board))

    if (boardAfterChange) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            board.squares = addAtRandomPosition(boardAfterChange)
            setBoard(board)
        }, 60)
    }
```

This is the moving function:

```
moved.forEach(movedItem => {
        let boardSquareClassName = ".boardSquare" + movedItem.from
        let gap = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".game")).rowGap)
        let movingDistance = ($(boardSquareClassName).width() + gap) * movedItem.steps
        //blink joined position
        // joinedPos.forEach(joinedItemPos => {
        //     arr[joinedItemPos] = {"tranform": "scale(1.2)"}
        // });

        if (movedItem.direction === "up")
            arr[movedItem.from] = { "transform": "translateY(-" + movingDistance + "px)" }
        else if (movedItem.direction === "down")
            arr[movedItem.from] = { "transform": "translateY(" + movingDistance + "px)" }
        else if (movedItem.direction === "right")
            arr[movedItem.from] = { "transform": "translateX(" + movingDistance + "px)" }
        else if (movedItem.direction === "left")
            arr[movedItem.from] = { "transform": "translateX(-" + movingDistance + "px)" }
    });

    setBoard({ squares: board.squares, styles: arr })
```

And this is the board render function:

```
const renderBoard = (boardArr) => {
    let counter = -1
    const jsx = (
        <div className="game">
            {boardArr.squares.map(number => {
                counter++
                return (
                    <div className="boardSquareWrapper" key={counter}>
                        <div key={counter} className={"boardSquare" + counter} style={boardArr.styles[counter] !== false ? boardArr.styles[counter] : { transform: "none" }} >
                            <div className={"boardSquareTextWrapper color" + number}>
                                <label className={"numberText" +
                                    (number.toString().length === 3 ? " threeDigitNumber" : "") +
                                    (number.toString().length === 4 ? " fourDigitNumber" : "")}>{number}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )

    return jsx
}
```

As u can see i'm basically making a transform and after the setTimeout i'm re rendering the board with the new positions. That's where the problem appear as the transform for split second start going back although it's a new board entirely.

Comment: Hey mudale, would be great if you could just provide a minimal reproductible example to that reproduce the 'bug' (in you case the transition). It's very painful for all developer that want to help you to clone the repo and search for the error.

Comment: Can you please put the minimal code that you have tried?

Comment: hey, i edited the question.